# How to get update_post_meta output to include string length

Tags: array, post-meta

I'm using the plugin WP All Import to import a special post type. The plugin includes an action hook pmxi_gallery_image that runs after the import that saves the attachment images to the post gallery.

I've included this action in a function in my function.php file in my child theme:

```
//After WP All Import runs this will place the attached photos in the gallery images field by post id
add_action('pmxi_gallery_image', 'update_images_meta', 10, 3);
function update_images_meta( $pid, $attid, $image_filepath ) {

// Get all the image attachments for the post
$param = array(
        'post_parent'       => $pid, 
        'post_type'         => 'attachment', 
        'post_mime_type'    => 'image'
);

$attachments = get_children( $param );

// Initialize the array
$atts = array();

// Fill the array with attachment ID's
foreach($attachments as $attachment) {
        $atts[] = $attachment->ID;
}

// Disable this hook which was overwrinting our changes
// remove_action( 'save_post', 'flexible_save_details', 10 );

// Update the post's meta field with the attachment arrays
update_post_meta( $pid, 'images', $atts );
}
```

This outputs an array of the image post id's:

```
a:4:{i:0;i:38985;i:1;i:38986;i:2;i:38987;i:3;i:38983;}
```

I need to include a string length before id, with the id's encapsulated in quotes, so the output looks like this for the gallery the theme uses:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:4:"7613";i:1;s:4:"7615";i:2;s:4:"7616";i:3;s:4:"7618";}
```

Comment: [`update_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) when saving an array will run [`wp_maybe_serialize()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize) which should automatically add the string count. If you're looking at the value **in the database** and it's not doing this, something is possibly wrong with your WordPress install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is being serialize properly. Your code saves an array of integers. Integers are not strings and so a string length is not saved. Run the following code and it should illustrate the point:

```
$str = 'a:4:{i:0;s:4:"7613";i:1;s:4:"7615";i:2;s:4:"7616";i:3;s:4:"7618";}';
$str = maybe_unserialize($str);
var_dump($str);
echo '<br/>';
var_dump(maybe_serialize($str));
echo '<br/>';
$str = array(
  1234,4567,8910,1112
);
var_dump(maybe_serialize($str));
echo '<br/>';
$str = array(
  '1234','4567','8910','1112'
);
var_dump(maybe_serialize($str));
```

To get the results you want, save strings and  not integers:

```
// Fill the array with attachment ID's
foreach($attachments as $attachment) {
        $atts[] = "$attachment->ID";
}
```